# verbatim html export of org headers

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How would you export org headers verbatim to HTML?

My org file looks like this:

```
#+TITLE: my-org-file.org

An example of org-style headers:

#+begin_example
* Title1
** Subtitle1a
** Subtitle1b
* Title2
** Subtitle2a
#+end_example
```

The expected output when exporting to HTML (`org-export-dispatch`; `C-c C-e h o`) is:

```
my-org-file.org

An example of org-style headers:

* Title1
** Subtitle1a
** Subtitle1b
* Title2
** Subtitle2a
```

The actual output is:

```
my-org-file.org

An example of org-style headers:#+beginexample

1 Title1
1.1 Subtitle1a
1.2 Subtitle1b
2 Title2
2.1 Subtitle2a

#+endexample
```

I have tried the other export options (`export ascii`, `quote`, `verse`, `html export`) and each produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply insert a leading space in front of each line in the example block:

```
#+TITLE: my-org-file.org

An example of org-style headers:

#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
 * Title1
 ** Subtitle1a
 ** Subtitle1b
 * Title2
 ** Subtitle2a
#+END_EXAMPLE
```